# Convert PHAsset/AVAsset to mp4 video in Nativescript app

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript, phasset, avasset

I use the `nativescript-imagepicker`-plugin for a filepicker.
This returns a `PHAsset`.
I have to copy it to a temporary directory to upload it.
Im new in iOS, so I tried a bit:

```
const options = PHVideoRequestOptions.new();
options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersion.Current;
PHImageManager
    .defaultManager()
    .requestAVAssetForVideoOptionsResultHandler(
        phAsset
        , options
        , (avAsset, audioMix, info) => {
            try {

                const tempFilePath = path.join(tempFolderPath, `${Date.now()}.mp4`);
                const targetURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(tempFilePath);
                const exportSession = AVAssetExportSession.alloc(avAsset, AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough);
                exportSession.outputUrl = targetURL;
                exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
                exportSession.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler(() => {
                    console.log(exportSession.status);
                });
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    );
```

My code crashes without error, so I don't know where to start to debug.
I want a MP4, to show it in web too.

At the end I need a string (path) to a mp4 file to upload id with `nativescript-background-http`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax seems to be wrong

```
const exportSession = AVAssetExportSession.alloc().initWithAssetPresetName(avAsset, AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough);
exportSession.outputURL = targetURL;
```

Comment: Thank! So I had a Typo AND missunderstand the found objC code-ecample